# Error : only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index How to solve?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to convert breast canser dataset to a dataframe and to use it
but i got following error;

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

```
#Import library
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd
#Load dataset
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
#Convert the sklearn.dataset cancer to a DataFrame.
df=pd.DataFrame(cancer.data,columns =[cancer.feature_names])
df['target']=pd.Series(data=cancer.target,index=df.index)
display(df['target'])
```

Comment: The example code runs without error.

Comment: To load directly as `pd.DataFrame` `df = load_breast_cancer(as_frame=True).frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset converts to a dataframe correctly. It seems to be an indexing issue, so I changed the last line to

```
df[["target"]]
```

and it worked for me.